# Python function not running, interpreter not giving any errors

Tags: python, function

I'm very new to Python and having a problem with a program I'm doing for a class.  main() and create_file work, but when it gets to read_file, the interpreter just sits there.  The program is running but nothing is happening.

The answer is probably something very simple, but I just can't see it.  Thanks in advance for any help.

I'm using IDLE (Python and IDLE v. 3.5.2)

Here's the code:

```
import random

FILENAME = "randomNumbers.txt"

def create_file(userNum):

    #Create and open the randomNumbers.txt file
    randomOutput = open(FILENAME, 'w')

    #Generate random numbers and write them to the file
    for num in range(userNum):
        num = random.randint(1, 500)
        randomOutput.write(str(num) + '\n')

    #Confirm data written
    print("Data written to file.")

    #Close the file
    randomOutput.close()

def read_file():

    #Open the random number file
    randomInput = open(FILENAME, 'r')

    #Declare variables
    entry = randomInput.readline()
    count = 0
    total = 0

    #Check for eof, read in data, and add it
    while entry != '':
        num = int(entry)
        total += num
        count += 1

    #Print the total and the number of random numbers
    print("The total is:", total)
    print("The number of random numbers generated and added is:", count)

    #Close the file
    randomInput.close()

def main():

    #Get user data
    numGenerate = int(input("Enter the number of random numbers to generate: "))

    #Call create_file function
    create_file(numGenerate)

    #Call read_file function
    read_file()

main()
```

Comment: `while entry != '':` You never change `entry` inside the loop, so it will keep looping forever.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually running? You defined some functions, but did you ever call them?

Comment: @Gator_Python Look at the last line: `main()`

Comment: Ah, thanks @Barmar I didn't scroll down.

Comment: @Barmar  You're right - I forgot to put entry = randomInput.readline() in the while loop - thank you!  I feel a bit stupid, lol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an infinite `while` loop in the function, since `entry` never changes during the loop.

The Pythonic way to process all the lines in a file is like this:

```
for entry in randomInput:
    num = int(entry)
    total += num
    count += 1
```

Comment: You can make it even *more* pythonic by wrapping using a context manager.

Comment: Thank you!  For some reason I thought the while loop would stop when it reached the end of the file.

Comment: I realize I forgot to put entry = randomInput.readline() inside the while loop.  Ugh, I feel stupid.